# python how to group two similar values from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the list of dictionaries below, I need to apply some operation where elements have similar and unique Shape and Color.  How can I group them using python or pandas?

```
mylist = [
    {'id': 11, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}, 
    {'id': 73, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}, 
    {'id': 33, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}, 
    {'id': 83, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'blue'}, 
    {'id': 34, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}
]

# grouped by Shape and Color
[{'id': 11, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}, {'id': 33, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}]
[{'id': 73, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}, {'id': 34, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}]
[{'id': 83, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'blue'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `groupby` and `to_dict('records')`:

```
result = [g.to_dict('records') for _,g  in pd.DataFrame(mylist).groupby(['Shape', 'Color'])]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[{'id': 11, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'},
  {'id': 33, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}],
 [{'id': 83, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'blue'}],
 [{'id': 73, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'},
  {'id': 34, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pure python:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by_keys(dictlist, keys):
    ret = defaultdict(list)
    for item in dictlist:
        key = tuple(item[k] for k in keys)
        ret[key].append(item)
    return list(ret.values())
```

and then use it with your values

```
mylist = [
    {'id': 11, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}, 
    {'id': 73, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}, 
    {'id': 33, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}, 
    {'id': 83, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'blue'}, 
    {'id': 34, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}
]

>>> group_by_keys(mylist, [])
[[{'Color': 'orange', 'Shape': 'circle', 'id': 11},
  {'Color': 'red', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 73},
  {'Color': 'orange', 'Shape': 'circle', 'id': 33},
  {'Color': 'blue', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 83},
  {'Color': 'red', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 34}]]

>>> group_by_keys(mylist, ['Shape'])
[[{'Color': 'orange', 'Shape': 'circle', 'id': 11},
  {'Color': 'orange', 'Shape': 'circle', 'id': 33}],
 [{'Color': 'red', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 73},
  {'Color': 'blue', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 83},
  {'Color': 'red', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 34}]]

>>> group_by_keys(mylist, ['Color', 'Shape'])
[[{'Color': 'orange', 'Shape': 'circle', 'id': 11},
  {'Color': 'orange', 'Shape': 'circle', 'id': 33}],
 [{'Color': 'red', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 73},
  {'Color': 'red', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 34}],
 [{'Color': 'blue', 'Shape': 'square', 'id': 83}]]
```

if you wanted to allow keys to be missing, you might want to do

```
MISSING = object()
  ...
  key = tuple(item.get(k, MISSING) for k in keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can accomplish this task without pandas with the following:**

*Though, you will likely encounter performance issues (without pandas or some distributed method) if your collection (`mylist`) exceeds 1M records.*

```py
# Create a collection of ids by color and shape
group_dict = dict()

for rec in mylist:
    shape = rec['Shape']
    color = rec['Color']
    id = rec['id']

    if shape not in group_dict:
        group_dict[shape] = dict()

    if color not in group_dict[shape]:
        group_dict[shape][color] = [id]
    else:
        group_dict[shape][color].append(id)


# Transform to records
records = []
for key, value in group_dict.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        rec = [dict(id=x, Shape=key, Color=k) for x in v]
        records.append(rec)

# result:
[[{'id': 11, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'},
  {'id': 33, 'Shape': 'circle', 'Color': 'orange'}],
 [{'id': 73, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'},
  {'id': 34, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'red'}],
 [{'id': 83, 'Shape': 'square', 'Color': 'blue'}]]
```